# Adjoint functors induce in representations of quivers? (references)

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory, adjoint-functors, quiver

Let $Q$ be a quiver and ${C}_1, C_2$ be two (small) categories. Let $F:C_1\rightarrow C_2$ and $G:C_2\rightarrow C_1$ be two (covariant) functors.

1. Is it true that if $F$ and $G$  induce functors
   $$
   F_Q: \text{Rep}_{C_1}(Q)\rightarrow\text{Rep}_{C_2}(Q) \quad \text{ and } \quad G_Q: \text{Rep}_{C_2}(Q)\rightarrow\text{Rep}_{C_1}(Q)?
   $$
   Here $\text{Rep}_C(Q)$ means the category of representations of $Q$ over the category $C$.
2. If so, is it true that if $F$ is a left adjoint of $G$, then $F_Q$ is a left adjoint of $G_Q$?

A demonstration is welcome, but if it is true I just need a reference as, for instance, a book or a paper.

Answer (score 1):

Given a quiver $Q$, there is an associated small category $\mathcal P$ (which is just the "free category" on the quiver -- you add an identity morphism for each vertex, and compositions of directed edges etc.). The category $\mathrm{Rep}_C(Q)$ is then the functor category $C^{\mathcal P}$.

Phrased this way your questions become fairly standard: your first question is  just a matter of understanding functor categories --- see e.g. chapter 2 of Riehl's book -- while the second question is a consequence of basic properties of adjunctions, see e.g. chapter 4 of Riehl's book.

Comment: specifically, (2) is Riehl's Proposition 4.4.6.